# Mean calculation for all columns and keeping the columns name

Tags: pandas, dataframe, average, multiple-columns, columnsorting

I have 2 CSV. files:

- On each one, the first raw is the distance from a specific point in the table (X-axis).
  [CSV1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2YAZ.png)
  [CSV2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRGVf.png)
- All the others rows are the distance from the camera (Z axis).

Because of interruptions some of the columns are empty(randomly). I want to calculate the average of each column in each CSV.

- Then subtract the average value from CSV1 by CSV2 **On the same X-axis value(same column)**.

Finally, The new CSV should show in the first row the distance on X-axis and in the second row the calculation results.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etjXZ.png)

Comment: its not clear can you post expected output please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the post.

Hopefully now its clearer [=

Comment: no to answer to yourself. Just edit the question